# Input parameters when generating HTML file?

Tags: aglio

I'm currently working with aglio to generate API specs for a few different service groups.  The issue I'm facing now is that I want to deploy the spec to multiple environments (for different consumer groups), so the displayed base URLs need to be different.

Is there any way to either send in a base URL for each HTML file generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the *include* feature `<!-- include(OtherFile.md) -->`.

In my case, I use a number of files:

- one toplevel file (e.g. `V1.md`), containing the [Metadata](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#metadata-section) and an overall introduction to the API
- one file per resource (e.g. `AuthResource.md`, `UserResource.md`), where I document only the functionality of that resource

The top-level file has an include-statement for each resource-file. In Aglio, I select only the top-level file.

In your case, you might be able to use customer-specific or environment-specific files *before* the top-level file. Move the Metadata to the customer-specific files and have them include the top-level file. Then you can render each customer-specific file into HTML.